# How to move /media to another disk device?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on a PC with one registered (admin) user called "john". When I run df, the results are:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      304439608 21668348 267283568   8% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1529584        4   1529580   1% /dev
tmpfs             308056     3872    304184   2% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1540276       80   1540196   1% /run/shm
none              102400       68    102332   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1      312568640  7625188 304943452   3% /media/john/Data
```

I see the second hard drive in my system /dev/sdb1 is mounted to /media/john/Data. Now, I don't know why there is a folder in /media named "john" when the /media folder is supposed to be for externally removeable devices, but whatever. What I want to do is put /media on /dev/sda1 where the rest of Ubuntu is mounted so I can free up the second hard drive to put an older version of Ubuntu on and, hopefully be able to dual-boot to either one.

The question of how to install a second, older (7.10), Ubuntu in parallel with the existing one (14.04) is another question for another day I suppose, but the first hurdle is freeing up that second hard drive, and in order to do that I need /media moved to /dev/sda1.

So how do I do that?

Comment: You cannot just change mount and make sdb available. The Data is still in sdb1 however you mount it. Do you just want to move data to sda1 or another partition on sda? Did you click on that sdb partition with Nautilus as that is a default mount now. They added user in path, possibly security. Or did you modify fstab to permanently mount it to that location. Post this: `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: That "john" is your user name.

Answer (score 0):

You move files either by dragging and dropping in the gui file manager, or with the `mv` command.